# Output redirect for wmic.exe using pipes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console-application, wmic

I'm writing a GUI app to wrap `wmic.exe`, using c++/win32api.
when calling to :

`CreateProcess(.., "wmic.exe" , ..)` 
I'm sending handles to input and output Pipe that I'v opened for that purpose, from which I'll later read the output ( and write the input to).

the same code worked for any other windows command line utilities that I'v checked (net.exe , tree.exe , etc..) however , it doesn't work on the case of `wmic.exe`. 
I've noticed that `wmic.exe` uses some functions of the `Console` family (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx) so I suspect that it might be the reason , but I don't really know whats going on inside there.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You can try using pipe in `cmd` to call `wmic`:

`echo CPU | wmic >test.log` ,

and it works on my 64-bit Windows 8 computer.

Comment: but it doesn't. as I said, the exact same code worked when only the image to run on `CreateProcess()` altered from `wmic.exe` to `net.exe` , `cmd.exe` etc..

Comment: @EdgarJamesluffternstat OK... Then it is a system-dependent problem, and unfortunately it seems not so easy to solve...

Comment: so far checked on XP32sp1/2/3 , win7-64bit , win7-64bit-over-WOW64 , windows8-64bit. thanks anyway.